# How to code this configuration logic in Scala?

Tags: scala, applicative

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178141/how-to-code-this-validation-logic-in-scalae)

Suppose I use the following logic (in quasi-Java) to get a configuration parameter `MyParam` :

```
String myParam = null

if ((myParam = getFromArgs("MyParam")) != null)
   return myParam

if ((myParam = getFromSystemProperties("MyParam")) != null)
   return myParam

if ((myParam = getFromUserConfigFile("MyParam")) != null)
   return myParam

... // and so on

if (myParam == null)
   error("No MyParam")
```

How to code this logic in Scala? Is `Applicative` applicable here?

Comment: The idea of monoids is probably more useful than applicatives here—xiefei's answer below takes advantage of the fact that `Option`'s `orElse` is essentially the plus operation for what's sometimes called the ["First" monoid instance](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) for `Option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment above, you can use a "First" monoid  instance for `Option` (really you only need a semigroup) to do this—for example, with [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def fo[A](a: A) = Option(a).fst

val param = (
  fo(myParam) |+|
  fo(getFromArgs("MyParam")) |+|
  fo(getFromSystemProperties("MyParam")) |+|
  fo(getFromUserConfigFile("MyParam"))
) getOrElse sys.error("No Param")
```

It's not necessarily preferable to the `orElse` versions using the standard library, but it highlights the relevant abstraction (note also that this version is lazy—the `getX` calls won't happen if they aren't needed).

Comment: Thanks. Semigroup does look like a relevant abstraction. Now I wonder how this abstraction can actual help in practice in this (or similar) example.

Answer (score 8):

```
List(getFromArgs _, getFromSystemProperties _, getFromUserConfigFile _).map{func=>
  Option(func("MyParam"))
}.reduce(_ orElse _).getOrElse(sys.error("No MyParam"))
```

Checkout [scala Option cheatsheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). Option is powerful.

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is only a matter of syntax, xiefei answer is exact.

If instead you are really looking for a flexible configuration I would suggest you warmly look to the Typesafe config project at : https://github.com/typesafehub/config/

Answer (score 3):

```
(
  Option(getFromArgs("MyParam")) orElse
  Option(getFromSystemProperties("MyParam")) orElse
  Option(getFromUserConfigFile("MyParam")) getOrElse
  error("No MyParam")
)
```